# Android Google Map V2 Authentication issue

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working on Google Map V2. I created API Key on Google Developer Console an also I Enabled Google Maps Android API. Integrated that API Key in my App. But whenever I run app on Map view it shows me below error.

I created  SHA-1 certificate fingerprint through debug.keystore
And I am working on Eclipse.

> 10-16 17:39:22.983: E/b(24170): Authentication failed on the server.
>   10-16 17:39:22.983: E/Google Maps Android API(24170): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
>   10-16 17:39:22.986: E/Google Maps Android API(24170): In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
>   10-16 17:39:22.986: E/Google Maps Android API(24170): Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
>   10-16 17:39:22.986: E/Google Maps Android API(24170): Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
>   10-16 17:39:22.986: E/Google Maps Android API(24170):   API Key: AIzaSyC2MVY7YknNfRtScZ45q7NcAADtF59IfnI
>   10-16 17:39:22.986: E/Google Maps Android API(24170):   Android Application (;): BE:7B:1E:07:B4:F0:F9:9E:74:09:CF:01:CC:F5:DF:EA:6E:4B:0D:E2;com.example.cc

I double checked API Key and its created.

Thanks

Comment: check your package name and api key you mentioned in  manifest

Comment: I just checked again its same which I give on Console

Comment: Probably you enter wrong SHA1 key in Google Developers console

Comment: I created Project 2 3 times but same issue

Comment: ssee this http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/google-maps/android-google-maps-v2-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks @Lakhan bro I am trying it. but in this example console is old.

Comment: but in new console it wont be tough..and are you using same pc..?

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="//place your API key here" />
```

If you have done it, then check the SHA1 key and the package name. The package name that you have given in the console and the package name in your build gradle -> applicationId  should be same. Ensure that you have given a genuine SHA1 key.